# For a married women, who's order is superior father or husband according to Islamic point of view?

Tags: quran, hadith, husband-wife, parents

Who's orders are superior for a married women father or her husband? What is in Islam about this thing?

Comment: I assume that this was asked before maybe somebody can find possible duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Islam provides complete code of social life and insist upon the family life, hence to create balance in society always husband order is superior for a wife than her father. However, as per teachings of Islam only anti Islamic can be ignored

Answer (score 1):

For married women, who is superior to a father or husband in Islam?
In order for cohabitation to flourish, it is necessary for both men and women to be each other's number one life after separating from their father's house and starting life with their spouse! But ... this does not mean that they should not take care of their parents or pay attention to them, but it does mean that the first priority of their life should be to change from parents to their spouse and give all the support and attention to their spouse.

Marriage means that you choose the person you love and want to spend the rest of your life with. After marriage, couples should give their most attention and support to their spouse. It is certain that parents also have a very important role in the life of every person and they should not be left alone after marriage. Parents may be at an age where they need their child more than ever. Couples should be careful to establish a relationship with their family that their spouse is also happy with. (2)

(1)Ref: https://www.eghtesadonline.com/%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%B4-%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A8%DB%8C%D8%AA-82/280840-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%B2%D9%86%D8%AF%DA%AF%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D9%BE%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1-%DB%8C%D8%A7-%D9%87%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%B1

(2)Ref: https://honarehzendegi.com/fa/Spouse-or-Parents-Priority

Answer (score 0):

Both prior answers are essentially correct. I may add some aspects:

We are bound to respect God and keep His commandments.

This is the first and the most important command.

God commanded us to respect our parents. Respecting the parents will *always* comprise to consider their advice seriously and *mostly* imply to follow it unless ...

the advice of the parents is against the Law of God. It is compulsory *not* to follow the advice of the parents if it is against oblibgatory Law of God.

Included is also any advice that makes it impossible to follow it without neglecting important obligations also backed by the commands of God. In general, it includes also to do what is makruh (allowed but against what God likes).

An important reason may include if obediance would create a major problem with the duties towards the own family. It is not obligatory to follow parents who command to divorce because divorce is disliked [⇗[1](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/47040/man-divorcing-his-wife-on-his-parents-orders)]. Commands that, if dirctly followed, would destabilise marriage should not be followed out of a mere feeling of obligation.

The obligation of a wife to follow the husband, or of a husband to respect the right of the bride are regulated for particular cases only, and many aspects are disputed.

In any case, for all who are involved, parents, daughter and son, it is *certainly better* to follow what is *mustahab*, what is good in the Will of God:

- Parents should do all in favour of their children, and avoid any damage. They should not use their authority unless they see their child in danger he or she is not able to recognise, knowing the situation and listening to their (in this case, grown-up) child.
- Husband and wife should love each other and make each other happy far beyond the obligations, according to their possiblities.

Obligatory law only sets limits to those who do not fervently search the Will of God. Those who do, and want to do good, will succeed and He will be with them.

Answer (score -1):

a woman's husband order is superior than any one else in ur family member including your father, brother ,father in law because husband have full right on his wife .